# What events does Stripe send when a payment method is not verified after 10 days

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

We are creating a webhook to handle events from Stripe.  From our understanding when a payment method is created in Stripe, it is set to a pending state.  Then after 10 days if it has not been verified then Stripe will send events indicating that the payment method has not been verified.

I am able to see that if I delete a payment method after it has been verified then a mandate.updated event indicating that the status of the payment method is inactive and a payemnt_method.attached event are sent.

I would like to know what events are sent automatically by Stripe if a payment method has not been verified after a certain number of days, so I can be sure to update the payment in our application correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming (based on the 10 day verification timeline) that you're referring to ACH Direct Debit payment methods specifically. From the Stripe docs [0]:

> In addition, microdeposit verifications have a timeout of 10 days. If you can’t verify microdeposits in that time, the PaymentIntent reverts to requiring new payment method details. Clear messaging about what these microdeposits are and how you use them can help your customers avoid verification issues.

After the 10 day mark, you would expect to receive the `payment_intent.requires_action` webhook Event, which will indicate that a Payment Method is required on the Payment Intent [1] and the `payment_intent.failed` webhook, indicating that the payment failed [2].

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=API#web-verify-with-microdeposits

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.requires_action

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-payment_intent.failed